# How to add in ListView only Keys (Firebase) start with specific Value

Tags: java, android, firebase

I make an application for android in java with cloud backend. I am newbie in Firebase and  I would like to add in a ListView only Keys (in Firebase e.g. Post1, Post4 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f31Y7.png)) that start with Value “Share” .I would appreciate if someone help me.

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = rootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue());
            HashMap<String, Object> users = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            listItems.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot childd : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = (String) childd.getValue().toString();
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        listItems);
                ex5ListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                listItems.add(name);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                System.out.println(name);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (name.startsWith("Share")) {
    listItems.add(name);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Btw, kindly fix your code snippets...